# error when selected value from ddl

Tags: c#

I had DDL and when I selected on it this error apear (operator `<` cannot be aplied with operand `String` or `int` )

```
 if (DDlCity.SelectedValue < 0)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
            {
                SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand("GetDealers", con);
                Com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(Com);
            DA.Fill(DT);
            GridView1.DataSource = DT;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Please read the compiler error message more closely and try to understand what it says. It says **“and”**, not “or”. It’s referring to the operand on each side of the operator, so `DDlCity.SelectedValue` is a `string` and `0` is (obviously) an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (DDlCity.SelectedIndex<0)

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `DDlCity.SelectedValue` to an appropriate type - it sounds like it's currently `string`. You'll need to parse it, e.g. with `int.TryParse` or `int.Parse`.

Comment: To all others: Next time when you see a question, you should type `I'm answering in 1 min` and post. Then you can edit it to your answer. Otherwise if you type the answer directly at first, you'll see a prompt at the top of page saying "a new answer has been posted(Click to load)" and you can see Jon Skeet's answer is exactly there, making you despaired. What you can do then is stop typing your answer and vote-up his.

Comment: Indeed. But SO team should right a `Jon-Skeet detector script` which automatically disables the POST text-box even while you're writing an answer and pop-up a message "Jon Skeet answering.." or something more relevant like "a new answer about to be posted from Jon Skeet(Click to hunt other questions while Jon is busy completing this answer. All the Best!)"

Comment: In addition to Daily Rep Cap, Jon Skeet should be restricted to answer more than one question within 15 minutes.